# Python REST API Issues

Tags: python, api, rest

I am working on a tool that queries a number of APIs, one of which is a RESTful API. All of the other functions (API calls) of my program work fine with requests.get(), however with the REST API, I do not seem to be able to access the actual content of the response, only the status code. i.e. when I simply print the response, (not response.status_code) I get: `<Response [200]>` output to the screen. Any ideas?

Snippet of code:

```
# The URL is correct in my program, For sure.
url = ('http://APIurl/%s' % entry)
    try:
       response = requests.get(url)

       # prints <Response [200]>
       print response

       # Fails, expecting JSON that isn't there
        results.append(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

print the response object's attributes to see what it has available:

```
print response.__dict__
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! Printed that to the console and it printed HTML code - a ton of it..

Comment: it should have a ton of HTML, with some other `"key":"value"` bits in it.

Answer (score 0):

[response.text](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) is your friend, if the content is not valid json.

Comment: This is also just printing out the html of the webpage that the API instructions are on.

Answer (score -1):

You need to print `response.context` or `response.text`. Your data is probably there.

Sometimes when your request is wrong, the API returns the whole error page (in HTML). So if you're getting a bunch of HTML code, make sure you're request parameters are ok.